# How to revert Homebrew to a previous state after an update

Tags: homebrew

I installed an app, which triggered an update of Homebrew and apparently also of some apps. Now I am unable to get some apps running, for example MySQL.

Some apps complain about not finding libicuuc.70.dylib after icu4c71.1 has been apparently installed by the update cycle.

I would like to revert the whole Homebrew installation to the point before the update was triggered to get my apps running again and to find out what went wrong. I can rely on TimeMachine.

Which directories do I have to replace through a backup?

I have the following directories in /usr/local :

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/Caskroom
/usr/local/Cellar
/usr/local/etc
/usr/local/Frameworks
/usr/local/Homebrew
/usr/local/include
/usr/local/lib
/usr/local/opt
/usr/local/remotedesktop
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/share
/usr/local/var
```

Comment: I think you should have use [pin](https://docs.brew.sh/Manpage#pin-installed_formula-), but that's too late now.  (About the question, about restoring: sorry ... )

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. The point is that you never know, what will break. If no-one can give me a hint, I will try to restore the whole /usr/local directory from Time Machine until I get a running system ...

Comment: The info "Some apps complain about not finding libicuuc.70.dylib after icu4c71.1 has been apparently installed by the update cycle." is a bit vague. After this my only guess would be: "restore all", because it's unknown what the exact error is, and what exactly has been updated. (Even when this info is available: I would not know if (partially) doing `brew uninstall ...` would help )

Comment: I am right now about to restore all the directories in /usr/local to the day before I installed flashrom, which triggered the update. I had problems with mysql, httpd as well as php not running. I was able to get httpd as well as php to start running through a reinstall, but mysql@5.6 does not behave... All three complained about not finding the icu4c libraries.

Comment: [mysql 5.6](https://endoflife.date/mysql) is end-of-life, since more than 1 year, so you should upgrade anyway 

Comment: I had mysql 8 running, but an homebrew update broke that.... This machine is on Mojave and Homebrew has decided to make life harder for mojave ...

Comment: I am having a macOS Catalina, which runs MySQL 8.0, installed using brew. I am only using this for some testing/experiments not for any production related stuff, and do not even make a backup.... 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I resorted to restoring the complete /usr/local directory from a Timemachine backup and got all homebrew installed applications running again.

I did the following:

1. delete the content in /usr/local.
2. enter Time Machine and go to a specific time in the past, where the system was still running
3. selected all the files and directories and restored them

The var directory gets generated automatically by the system, once it is deleted, but it there where no conflicts. At first I tried to restore with out deleting the content of /usr/local before restoring it, but I got an error and the restore did not complete. After deleting it before the restore everything went through.

I still do not know what broke my system and would like to know more about Homebrew. In the time I am using homebrew it changed a lot the way it works and consequently my experience and the unexpected results I get sometimes.